# Create a distributable Eclipse bundle on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, bundle

our company uses the Eclipse IDE with some plugins that are required to start our platform. I want to **create a bundle** for our Java developers that contains the latest Eclipse Java (Oxygen) with the plugins already installed.

So far I've installed Eclipse with

```
sudo cask brew install eclipse-java
```

which created an `/Application/Eclipse Java.app`.

After installing the plugins within Eclipse with Help->Install New Software the `~/.eclipse/` was created in my home directory.

Is there some way to zip these folders to create an distributable package of eclipse or am I missing other files/directories?

Is it possible to move the plugins in the installation directory as well?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use any Eclipse distribution that's produced by packaging tools. It's best to download directly from eclipse.org, for various reasons.

As for customizing an Eclipse "package" for distribution yourself, have a look at the Oomph project, which is designed for that exact purpose (and others). Oomph is what produces both the installer and the downloadable packages of Eclipse IDE releases. You can read specifically about [Oomph authoring here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official eclipse installer. There is an advanced mode to disable the p2 pooling. Then using this mode, everything will go into the eclipse folder. Afterwards you can zip it and give it to others. Of course you are always bound to the CPU Arch still.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).